# Having a variable to an inner class from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently working on a 10x10 grid which I'll need to alter the selected box or the box with its neighbours. In order to do that, I thought I need a pop-up (to set the changes). I don't have a button to make the pop-up appear, I simply need the coordinates for that.
I have tried this code but in the private void viewClick() method, the variables are set to 0.
Everything before that works fine. How can I keep the values of the variables?

MainActivity:

```
View gView;
GameCoords mGame;
private int xx, yy;

public void setCol(int column){
    this.yy = column;
    System.out.println(" y : " + xx + yy);  //fine
}
public void setRow(int row){
    this.xx = row;
    System.out.println("x  : " + xx );  //fine
}

public int getRow(){
    return xx;
}
public int getCol(){
    return yy;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGame = new GameCoords ();

    gView = findViewById(R.id.view);
    gView.setOnClickListener(new ViewClick());
}

private void viewClick(){
    System.out.println(" On create sfter ships : " + xx + yy);  //both are 0
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.select_ship, null, false), 1000, 700, true);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.view),
            Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "X + Y" + xx + yy  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public class ViewClick implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewClick();
    }
}
```

GameCoords (where the variables acquired):

```
public int clickedCoords(int column, int row) {

    System.out.println("Game class " + row + column);   //received fine

    mainActivity.setRow(row);
    mainActivity.setCol(column);
    return 0;
}
```

So, what should I do to have xx and yy in the viewClick method with their values. 
I wanted to challenge myself with an easy looking task but it seems is not. Any lead, hint or code piece appreciated.

I tried to use getters as well but they didn't work either.
Edit 2: When I declare the xx to 12 (private int xx = 12;) without getting/setting, it works perfectly fine in the inner class. My code has a problem with getting the numbers from some other classes

Comment: Check the other methods provided by on click listener

Comment: @briantaurostack7 like what? I am having the coordinates from a class extended by View. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener I only found this.

Comment: I f there are no methods in the on click listener , try using static variables to maintain the state.

Comment: Making the variables (xx and yy) worked! Thanks a lot, man. I have been just working on this problem for +2 hours, I wish I have asked before...